# Issue with .mouseleave() and .mouseenter()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use .mouseenter() and .mouseleave() to make an animation to my button.The problem is that when I move my cursor across the button multiple times it keeps repeating the animation .For .mouseenter() I want it to complete the animation once the cursor keeps hovering over it till the animation time is complete and if it leaves the button before the animation is complete the animation should stop.For .mouseleave() the animation should stop if the cursor hovers over it before the animation is complete.

```js
    
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#ffce00',width:'+=1em'},100);
    });
    $('#button').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#1e7989',width:'-=1em'},100);
    });   
  });
```

```css
#button{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.color-animation/1/mainfile"></script>
<div id="button"></div>
```

Comment: You mention that it keeps repeating the animation. What is it that you're wanting it to do?

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this with jquery? you could achieve the same effect with css.

Comment: That's how those events are supposed to work. If you want to stop the animation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211280/how-to-stop-an-animation-queue-in-jquery

Comment: When you leave the button only then the animation is triggered and then when you enter, I cant see when you are over and doing left right in boundaries

Comment: Post updated,sorry I forgot to add what I want it to do.

Comment: Could you also add what should happen to width of element when you do a mouseleave / mouseenter during animation?

Comment: The same for the width animation.I want that to happen for both the background-color animation and the width animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flags for entering and leaving. Then check the appropriate flag, and finish the current animation when an enter/leave event occurs, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isEntering = false, // Create flags
        isLeaving = false;
    $('#button').mouseenter(function () {
        isEntering = true; // Set enter flag
        if (isLeaving) {   // Check, if leaving is on process
            $(this).finish(); // If leaving, finish it
            isLeaving = false; // Reset leaving flag
        }
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor: '#ffce00',
            width: '+=1em'
        }, 100);
    });
    $('#button').mouseleave(function () {
        isLeaving = true; // Set leave flag
        if (isEntering) { // Check if entering is on process
            $(this).finish(); // If it is, finish it
            isEntering = false; // Reset enter flag
        }
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor: '#1e7989',
            width: '-=1em'
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpywxn5o/).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.stop()`, it will stop the animations from queueing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor:'#ffce00',width:'+=1em'},100);
    });
    $('#button').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor:'#1e7989',width:'-=1em'},100);
    });
});
```

Regards,
Gados

Comment: When I move my cursor multiple times across the div, it shrinks till it disappear .

Answer (score 0):

If you only want it to run one time you can unbind it after the event fires:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#ffce00',width:'+=1em'},100);
        $(this).unbind('mouseenter');
    });
    $('#button').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#1e7989',width:'-=1em'},100);
        $(this).unbind('mouseleave');
    });   
  });
```

Comment: Isn't this what `.one()` is for?

Comment: But I don't think you understand the question. He doesn't want it to happen just once, he just doesn't want them to overlap.