# Trigger CSS animation only if button has not been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the following code, on [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) the `#wrap` element's height in animated via jQuery `animate()`.

On `handlerIn` the element gains 250px of height and on `handlerOut` it loses 250px of height.

The issue is that I've also included a "button" that gives the user the ability to remove that 250px of height that is added on `.hover(handlerIn)`. When the user clicks this "button", then moves the mouse outside of the `hover` element (`handlerOut`); the `hover` element loses 250px twice.

I'd like to only trigger the `.hover(handlerOut)` function if the user has **not** clicked the "button".

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s07ywqxw/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#wrap").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).animate({height: '+=250'}, 'slow');
      $('#button').css('display', 'block');
      expanded = true;
      console.log("expanded is " + expanded);
    },
    function () {
      $(this).animate({height: '-=250px'}, 'slow');
      $("#button").hide();
      expanded = false;
      console.log("expanded is " + expanded);
    }
  );
  $('#wrap').on('click', function(){
    window.open('http://google.com', 'click', 'window settings');
    return false;
    console.log('click');
  });
  if(expanded = true){
    $("#button").on('click', function(){
        $('#wrap').animate({height: '-=250px'}, 'slow');
        $("#button").hide();
        return false;
      });
  };

});
```

Comment: simply just have a global variable to see if x is clicked and in mouseout have an if statement before executing the animation ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop an animation queue in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211280/how-to-stop-an-animation-queue-in-jquery) and a multitude of others found by searching SO.

Comment: ye i would say too: $('#wrap').stop().animate...

Comment: If you ask me, I would just switch between 2 CSS classes, or even toggle just an "expended" class. Let CSS transitions do all the work.

Comment: That isn't what he's asking guys - read the question thoroughly, and view the fiddle before speculating!

Comment: A proper way would be to trigger the `mouseout` event when you click on `$("#button")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Though I don't necessarily think you're going about this the right way) You need to make sure you're setting expanded to false after you click the X, i.e., telling the code that the box is no longer expanded and that it shouldn't reduce the size of the box further:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#wrap").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).animate({height: '+=250'}, 'slow');
      $('#button').css('display', 'block');
      expanded = true;
      console.log("expanded is " + expanded);
    },
    function () {
      $(this).animate({height: '-=250px'}, 'slow');
      $("#button").hide();
      expanded = false;
      console.log("expanded is " + expanded);
    }
  );
  $('#wrap').on('click', function(){
    window.open('http://google.com', 'click', 'window settings');
    return false;
    console.log('click');
  });
  if(expanded = true){
    $("#button").on('click', function(){
        $('#wrap').animate({height: '-=250px'}, 'slow');
        $("#button").hide();
        return expanded = false;    //This is all I changed
      });
  };

});
```

That works. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omgtoblerone/s07ywqxw/3/)

**EDIT**

A word of warning - you should really think twice before using the `jQuery.animate()` function. Compared to say, something like CSS animations or a *far* better js animation platform like GSAP, the `jQuery.animate()` function is around **10x slower** ::[reference](https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/).

Personally I'd use GSAP, but either way you shouldn't spend much more time learning this workflow - it will only hinder you in the future!